# Add dynamic element onClick and make link disable then removing it with link clickable again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add an dynamic input element `onClick` with jQuery and make the link disable. On deleting the input element that I just added I want to make the link clickable again.

[image: screenshot]

I did the first part of adding element and making the link disable but the problem is when I add multiple elements and try to delete only one element all other links become clickable. I know, because I have given class to dropdown links. Not sure what to do to get this working right.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".list").on('click', function() {
    $("#blockFeild").append(
      '<div class="row parent">' +
      '<div class="col-md-8">' +
      '<input class="form-control"  type="text">' +
      '</div>' +
      '<button class="btn btn-info" id="editbtn"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>' +
      '<button class="btn btn-danger" id="removebtn"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>' +
      '<br><br>' +
      '</div>'
    ).show();
  });
});

$(document).on('click', 'a.list ', function() {
  $(this).addClass('no-click');
});

$(document).on('click', 'li.block', function() {
  $(this).addClass('not-allowed');
});

$(document).on("click", "#removebtn", function() {
  $(this).closest('.parent').remove();
  $(".block").removeClass("not-allowed");
  $(".list").removeClass("no-click");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Add Block
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <?php $users_fields=$ this->db->list_fields('users'); for ($i=0; $i
    <count($users_fields); $i++){ ?>
      <li class="block">
        <a class="list" href="#">
          <?php echo $users_fields[$i]?>
        </a>
      </li>
      <?php } ?>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem stems from duplicate ids (#removebtn, remember ids must be unique) and also this section of your code:

```
    $(".block").removeClass("not-allowed");
    $(".list").removeClass("no-click");
```

These two lines grab all elements on the page with the classes "not-allowed", and "no-click" respectively and then remove those classes. This is why the removal of one of your rows enables all your dropdown links again.

You need to create a way to associate a generated row with ONLY the link used to generate it, perhaps through the addition of an identifying class on both the row and link. That way when the row is destroyed you can use jQuery to grab that specific link element and re-activate it.

Comment: you are right but i am not sure how can i associate row with link should i give id's to the link or row ?

Comment: with your idea and a lot of thinking i am able to solve this problem :)

Answer (score 1):

#### UPDATE

Now that I understand the OP better I updated this Snippet with `.index()` and `.eq()` in order to associate the correct `.block .list` with a matched `.removebtn`. Also replaced `.remove()` with `.hide()`. Works perfect.

Change all ids to classes. ex. from `#removebtn` to `.removebtn`. You can only have unique ids. When elements are generated, they have the same id, so that's why they are all affected. <del>I don't quite fully understand OP's objective,</del> but I bet having duplicate ids is the root of the problem.

In order to remove a `.parent.row` on it's own `.removebtn` replace the last 4 lines with these lines:

```
$('.list').on('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('no-click');
});

$('.block').on('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('not-allowed');
});


$(document).on("click", '.removebtn', function(e) {
  var tgt = $(this);
  idx = tgt.closest('.row').index()
  $('.block').eq(idx).removeClass('not-allowed').find('.list').removeClass('no-click');
  tgt.closest('.row').hide();
});
```

#### SNIPPET

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".list").on('click', function() {
    $(".blockfield").append(
      '<div class="row parent">' +
      '<div class="col-md-8">' +
      '<input class="form-control" type="text">' +
      '<button class="btn btn-info editbtn"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>' +
      '<button class="btn btn-danger removebtn"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>' +
      '<br><br>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>'
    ).show();
  });
});

$('.list').on('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('no-click');
});

$('.block').on('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('not-allowed');
});


$(document).on("click", '.removebtn', function(e) {
  var tgt = $(this);
  idx = tgt.closest('.row').index()
  $('.block').eq(idx).removeClass('not-allowed').find('.list').removeClass('no-click');
  tgt.closest('.row').hide();
});
```

```css
.no-click {
  pointer-events: none;
}
.not-allowed {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Add Block
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">

    <li class="block">
      <a class="list" href="#">1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="block">
      <a class="list" href="#">2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="block">
      <a class="list" href="#">3</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
<section class='blockfield'>

</section>
```

Comment: I have updated the code but the problem is not solved yet :)

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem previously that my code does not work with

```
$(document).on.....
```

So firstly you change the duplication of ids as foxinatardis said and test this:

```
$(document).delegate('.class_off_button', 'click', function (){
    //what you want to do
});
```

Comment: `.delegate()` is deprecated, and `.on()` is it's replacement.